# automated django receive hook on server: respond to collectstatic with "yes"

Tags: django, git, hook

I'm using a Github post-recieve hook to run a bash file that pulls both my repos.

```
#!/bin/sh
cd ~/public_html/repo_static
env -i /usr/bin/git pull origin master
cd ~/django-code/repo_django
env -i /usr/bin/git pull origin master
```

I also want to `collectstatic` on the django repo. How do I automate the "yes" response to that?

I can't use [Fabric](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.3.0/index.html) because unfortunately the team chose to work with Python 2.4 for the time being. Is there a way to automate collectstatic without Fabric?

Comment: People landing on this question may also be interested in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38862567/gcloud-app-deploy-flag-to-automate-prompting) about non-interactive gcloud deployments.

Answer (score 249, accepted):

```
python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
```

Comment: Wouldn't that default to no option?

Comment: @Danil afaik is not

Comment: It does not default to no option, see the `collectstatic.py` lines 174-185

Answer (score 17):

If you'd like to specify the default answer, you could also just pipe it into the command:

```sh
$ echo yes | python manage.py collectstatic
```

or

```sh
$ echo no | python manage.py collectstatic
```

Comment: @Paullo It may be an issue with permissions or the shebang in `manage.py`. I edited the command to be called by `python` executable explicitly.