# gcloud app deploy, flag to automate prompting?

Tags: gcloud

Is it possible to do silent deployment when using `gcloud app deploy`

When I run the command `gcloud app deploy ./deployment/app.yaml --version v1` its always prompting for

`Do you want to continue (Y/n)?  Y`

how to automate this? 
is there any flag that we can pass in to mute this?

Comment: People landing on this question may also be interested in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8705305/automated-django-receive-hook-on-server-respond-to-collectstatic-with-yes) about bypassing Django's collectstatic command's confirmation prompt.

Answer (score 149, accepted):

You're looking for the `--quiet` flag, available across all `gcloud` commands:

```
$ gcloud --help
     --quiet, -q
    Disable all interactive prompts when running gcloud commands. If input
    is required, defaults will be used, or an error will be raised.
```

Comment: Firebase tools already had `--non-interactive`. Why introduce a different flag with a much more ambiguous name? Quiet... 

Comment: `$ google ask --question="Why?" --quiet`

Answer (score 6):

```
    $ gcloud app deploy --quiet
```

Or also:

```
    $ gcloud app deploy -q
```